# CakePhp :: Missing fields on create / insert into query

Tags: php, cakephp, constraints, cakephp-2.3

I'm new to CakePhp and currently trying to implement a simple ticket system with Tickets, Events, Tasks, Users and so on. Beneath a basic CRUD functionality a Ticket whose status has been marked done via ajax call, should generate a new Ticket (representing the next step in a workflow).

However the creation of the next Ticket in `Ticket::afterSave()` as callback to `$this->saveField()` via ajax ultimately fails with an **Integrity Constraint Violation**, while a 'normal baked' `edit()` call works.
Cake simply seems to ignore some of the to-be-saved fields on `$this->save()` in the generated 
**MySQL INSERT INTO statement** and i can't come up with an explanation.

Here the model of the **Ticket**...

```
<? class Ticket extends AppModel {

    // [...]

    public function update($status) {

        return $this->saveField('status', $status);
    }

    public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {

        //[...] if ticket state was changed to done:

        // generate data for Ticket with next Task in Workflow
        $this->Event->id = $this->field('event_id'); 
        $ticketData = $this->Event->generateNext();

        // check if data is correct
        debug($ticketData);

        // create new ticket
        $this->create();

        return $this->save($ticketData);

    }
}
```

A `Ticket` `belongs_to` `User`, `Task` and `Event` The **Event** of the completed Ticket generates the next ticket's data `Event->generateNext()` (with help of LinkableBehavior, since containable doesn't seem to support deep conditions). The data is correct, the debug above **always** prints like:

```
array(

    'Ticket' => array(
        'event_id' => '11720',
        'task_id' => '9',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'status' => 'Requested')
    )
```

However when ajax-calling the `update` function, the creation fails with:

```
Error: [...] Integrity constraint violation: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`table`.`tickets`, CONSTRAINT `fk_tickets_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) [...])
```

...showing the SQL Query:

```
'INSERT INTO `table`.`tickets` (`status`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('Requested', '2014-02-05 22:00:32', '2014-02-05 22:00:32')'
```

As you can see the generated query misses the fields for`user_id` an so on completely, which of course causes the creation to fail. But the debug proves their existence?! Confusing.
When calling a `Ticket::save()` in the baked `edit` function however the query turns out nicely like:

```
'INSERT INTO `table`.`tickets` (`status`, `event_id`, `task_id`, `user_id`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('Requested', 11720, 9, 1, '2014-02-05 20:34:25', '2014-02-05 20:34:25')'
```

I suppose i could avoid this behavior by using a custom query like `Ticket->query()` ? But i'd rather like to understand the different outcomes and do it the 'cake way'.
I hope this was somehow understandable and would really appreciate any help.

Many, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating the new Ticket from within the afterSave() method of Ticket itself after the initial update of the status field, the model's whitelist is set to the only field you were initially saving (status).
All other fields are discarded by

```
$this->save($ticketData);
```

Change that to:

```
$this->save($ticketData, false, array(
    'event_id',
    'task_id',
    'user_id',
    'status'
);
```

Watch out for recursive calls to afterSave(). The above call $this->afterSave() WILL call again afterSave() itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, savedario! Your solution works like a charm.
Suddenly my confusion feels really stupid.. i'll dig into cake's whitelists at once. Also thanks for mentioning the recursive calls, i think as long as the next ticket is not marked 'done' yet it should be fine.

Comment: You're welcome. I stumbled myself into this only a few hours earlier.